# How should I frame these sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses, sentence-usage

If you would have told me I would have done it.

I would mind if you wouldn't do it.

I wouldn't mind if you would do it.

If you wouldn't have told me I would have done it.

Are there sentences correct?

Comment: You could have checked before posting: would can't be used in two clauses like that.

Answer (score 0):

No, these sentences are not correct.Here are the correct sentences:

If you had told me, I would have done it (3rd Conditional)

I would mind if you didn't do it(2nd conditional) or it could also be - I will mind if you don't do it(1st conditional), depending on the context.If the situation is unlikely to happen or highly improbable, we use second conditional.

I would not mind if you didn't do it (2nd conditional)

If you had not told me, I would have done it(3rd conditional)

p.s - Also notice the comma.Use a comma after the if clause when the if clause precedes the main clause

You can easily find about this on google.Just type " if Conditionals "